# Verify format code with SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table account contains attributes `id` and `account number`.

```
id   account number
--------------------
 1   007-000068
 2   007-000069
```

I need to verifiy an account number if it is in this format `"XXX-XXXXXXXX"`, `X` is variable

Comment: This is obviously doable, and Gordon's answer would work widely across various SQL technologies, but is SQL the right place for this validation? Just something to think about.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please have a look at [tour]. You may also want to check [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask], and how to create a [mcve]. Post the code you have tried and the errors you have received. Be as specific as possible as it will lead to better answers.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using this pattern:

```
select id, accountnumber,
       (case when accountnumber like '[0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
             then 1 else 0
        end) as isValid
```

This assumes that you are expecting digits in each of the positions.

Comment: run this one time to find any problems to fix, then make it into a check constraint to prevent further problems: *alter table account
add constraint CK_account_account_number ([account number] like '[0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]');* Also, think about removing the spaces in your column name, it will be a hassle to [bracket] it everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

The following should work (pick the one you need):

```
SELECT id, [account number]
  , IIF([account number] LIKE '___-________', 1, 0) AS IsValidStructure
  , IIF([account number] LIKE '[0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]', 1, 0)
      AS IsValidWithOnlyDigits
FROM TableName
```

For more explanation check out official documentation on possible wildcards: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx

**NOTE:** The `IIF` clause is available from SQL Server 2012. For lower versions `CASE` should be used like **Gordon Linoff** used it in his answer.

Comment: May be worth noting that `IIF` is only available in 2012 and up in case OP is using an older version of SQL Server.